# How do I authenticate for Jira API with PHP

Tags: php, json, jira, javascript-objects, jira-rest-api

I have written this small code to get the information about a user profile from Jira Service Desk.
Now the problem is that I don't know how to authenticate with the API, so I get an authentication error. Is there a more or less easy way to do this? Or something a beginner should stay away from until later.

My "code":

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=username');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
echo $query
```

The error:

> 401Client must be authenticated to access this resource.1

Comment: are you trying to authenticate using jira authentication or you want to access to  some data according to your credentials from the jira api ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI I want to access the data with credentials to later be able to change it.

Comment: changing data of user ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI well, my own profile/user for the start. Just to play around and get a bit more comfortable with it

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);`

Comment: $header = array();
$header[] = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.":".$password);
$header[] = "Content-Type: application/json";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the message error you have, it seems that you should send credentials to get information from the endpoint.

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/user?username=username');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password"); // replace with username and password. 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($ch);
echo $query;
```